# Searchkick substring matches lookup

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm thinking this might be a question for the wider ElasticSearch community, but since we're using Searchkick, I thought I'd start here...

We have an index containing records with multiple string fields, say:

1. "Jimi", "Hendrix", "Guitar"
2. "Phil", "Collins", "Drums"
3. "Sting", "", "Bass"
4. "Ringo", "Starr", "Drums"
5. "Paul", "McCartney", "Bass"

I want to pass searchkick/elasticsearch a **long** string, say:

"It is known that **Jimi** liked to set light to his **guitar** and smash up all the **drums** while on stage."

and i want to get returned the fields that have any matches - preferably in order of the most matches first:

- "**Jimi**", "Hendrix", "**Guitar**"
- "Phil", "Collins", "**Drums**"
- "Ringo", "Starr", "**Drums**"

How do I go about setting up the query?

Thanks!